# perform groupby to find cumulative count on assignment Id between a range of dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe at Assignment Id level which includes dates of submission, student Id. I want to find number of assignments submitted by a student in past 12 months(excluding latest entry) wrt latest entry. Assignment Id is the unique key.
I want the cumulative count to be made basis Assignment Id.

I tried using groupby to perform this step but couldnt find the desired output.
I want my answer in python.

what I have

```
Assmt id    student id  date of submission
106473754   100357          2/1/2016
102485554   100357          3/1/2016
108474032   100357          4/1/2016
101663805   100357          2/1/2017
307953885   100364          5/1/2017
307252429   100364          7/1/2017
304205214   100364          11/1/2017
304041247   100364          11/1/2017
512459298   100364          2/1/2018
```

what i want

```
student id  date of submission  count_in_12_mon
100357            2/1/2017                       3
100364            2/1/2018                       4
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to find the `max` value for each group using `transform` , then convert the `datetime` to months and compare with all  `date of submission`, then assign the value back , using `agg`

```
s=df.groupby('studentid')['dateofsubmission'].transform('max')
s1=(s.dt.year*12+s.dt.month-df.dateofsubmission.dt.year*12-df.dateofsubmission.dt.month)
df['New']=((s1>0)&(s1<=12))
yourdf=df.groupby('studentid').agg({'New':'sum','dateofsubmission':'last'}).reset_index()
yourdf
Out[851]: 
   studentid dateofsubmission  New
0     100357       2017-02-01  3.0
1     100364       2018-02-01  4.0
```

Comment: Hi...This works well. Could you explain the code a bit. What are you passing into df['New'] ?

Comment: Also, this is not counting as per my assignment id, but over the occurences in date

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code:

```
df['date of submission'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date of submission'])
df2 = df.groupby('student id', as_index=False)['date of submission'].last()
df2['count_in_12_mon'] = df.groupby('student id')['date of submission'].first().dt.year.tolist()
df2['count_in_12_mon'] = df2.apply(lambda x: df.loc[(df['date of submission'].dt.year == x[2]) & (df['student id'] == x[0])].count(), axis=1)
```

And now:

```
print(df2)
```

Is:

```
   student id date of submission  count_in_12_mon
0      100357         2017-02-01                3
1      100364         2018-02-01                4
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but does it take in account the 12 month duration that i mentioned>

Comment: @Curious Strange, please copy the whole thing and try it again, it works for me, after it works, please up-vote and accept it.